# How to give a value in column based on other columns

Tags: r

I have a df as follows

```
V1| V2| V3| V4
--+---+---+---
10| 1 | 3 | 2
2 | 1 | 1 | 0
0 | 3 | 0 | 2
2 | 0 | 1 | 1
0 | 0 | 2 | 3
2 | 2 | 0 | 4
```

I want to write a program, so that
if ( V1 != 0 ) then V2,v3,v4 all will be 0
Similarly, if V1==0 and V2 != 0 then V3, V4 are zero and so on.

I am trying the for loop and if statement but not getting anywhere. Can someone help

expected out put

```
V1| V2| V3| V4
--+---+---+---
10| 0 | 0 | 0 
2 |0  | 0 | 0
0 | 3 | 0 | 0 
2 | 0 | 0 | 0 
0 | 0 | 2 | 0 
2 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: Reproducible example and expected output please.

Comment: Please, describe what you've done already and what was wrong with results.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting this to solved in one liner with `max.col` but I couldn't figure out a way. So here is a lengthy procedure.

```
#For each row find out its 1st value which is greater than zero
indx <- max.col(df > 0, ties.method = "first")

#Convert the dataframe to matrix
mat <- as.matrix(t(df))

#Get the indices which we need to convert to zero
indices <- setdiff(1:(nrow(df) * ncol(df)), rep(ncol(df), length(indx)) * 
                                            (seq_along(indx) - 1) + indx)

#The output of rep(ncol(df), length(indx)) * (seq_along(indx) - 1) + indx is 
#[1]  1  5 10 13 19 21 
#which are the indices which we don't want to change to zero.

# Convert those indices to zero
mat[indices] <- 0
data.frame(t(mat))


#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#  10  0  0  0
#   2  0  0  0
#   0  3  0  0
#   2  0  0  0
#   0  0  2  0
#   2  0  0  0
```